# UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey not found

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate, swift4.2

UIApplicationDelegate method - [application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) showing an error with Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10).

> **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey not found**

What is replacement of `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey` in Swift 4.2?

[image]

Comment: already you added the new key name in your attached method  [application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) , then why created the ? here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey' has been renamed to 'UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey'. Replace 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey' with 'UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey'.

Click on error hint, will show you solution:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Xcode would fix-it but `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey` is replaced by a nested type `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey`, Please find following [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the below snippet of the code and worked for me.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

}
```

Just provide UIApplication in launchOptions.
Hopes it will work for you as well. :)